# Computer Suddenly started waking up from sleep by itself

Tags: windows-7, sleep

My PC was functioning fine for a longtime until last night when I went to sleep it suddenly turned itself on. I made it sleep again and around 10 mins later it went on again.

So I ran powercfg lastwake and found that my ACPI power button was the problem?.....

Nobody could have touched the power button and I have disabled waking up with mouse and keyboard. A ghost maybe? lol

Comment: Do you use TeamViewer? A recent version of TeamViewer had a bug that caused this issue. I'm not sure if it's been fixed yet.

Answer (score 1):

My Thinkpad X61T dockec in Ultradock does the same when I have Thinkpad USB keyboard attached. There are times it does not fire up from sleep, but to ensure that it stays in sleep, I typically remove the USB keyboard before putting it to sleep.

But, given your scenario of disabling wake up with mouse and keyboard there could be other ways the machine is woken up. You might want to list out what you have attached.

Sometimes the network adapters can also play into it and wake up the OS from sleep.

The surest way to ensure it does not come up is disconnect & disable most connections and peripherals and see if that prevents this from happening.

Also, they can be attached/ removed via a process of elimination to go through the peripherals.

That's how I figured out it was my keyboard causing it.

PS: Maybe one of your forefathers has found this as a medium to garner your attention :)

Additional:

Pointing out some examples of peripherals that have their power issues.

- [Hard Drive](https://superuser.com/a/10933/183467)
- [Mouse/ pointing device](https://superuser.com/a/80999/183467)
- [Network Adapter](https://superuser.com/a/86883/183467)
- [Other possibilities?](https://superuser.com/questions/380891/system-insomnia-wakes-up-after-50-seconds-after-going-to-sleep?rq=1)