# Laptop will not wake from external keyboard or mouse

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep

So I got a USB keyboard and external monitor to use with my laptop while the lid is closed. It worked great the first couple of weeks, I was able to wake it by pressing a button or shaking the mouse just like a desktop. Now it has stopped working, and I have to open the lid and press the keyboard or power button to wake it. I enabled the wake from USB setting in the BIOS, and verified a handful of other things that should have solved it, but here I am.

If I lift the lid and press a button on the built in keyboard, it lights up temporarily but then proceeds to shut down. It requires that I plug in the power cord and press the power button to get it going again. The battery is not dead, however. Immediately after logging in the battery shows 90% charged. Very odd behavior, I'd really appreciate some help with this. Thanks

Comment: There should be a Fn button on your laptop to wake it up (if the lid was already open for example).  Can you identify this Fn key sequence and then use that on your external keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried just disabling the lid completely? How long does the laptop last on battery only?

Comment: Maybe this Super User [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/956448/laptop-wont-wake-from-sleep-when-external-keyboard-and-mouse-are-plugged-in-via) can help